# Is base-emitter voltage of BJT transistor (common emitter configuration) constant?

Tags: transistors, common-emitter

[image]

For sillicon the value of Vbe is approximately 0.7 V. So why is the input characteristics of such a transistor like this

[image]

Why not a straight vertical line. Or is this curve plotted for I Vs Vbb. I have seen nowhere plotting this curve against Vbb.

So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong here is that you have read that 'VBE is approximately 0.7v', and now you're wondering why transistors don't follow that rule exactly.

The thing is, transistors do what they do. Then we make up simplified descriptions of their behaviour, called models.

A model gets used by a lot of people if it's found to be useful. [George Box, all models are wrong, but some are useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)

For 95% of my transistor use, the approximation 'VBE=0.7v' is enough for me to make a good design. In the remaining 5%, it's a valuable first pass, and a good cross-check on whether a more detailed model gives a plausible answer.

To explain the shape of, and the difference between, those transistor curves, you can elaborate the transistor model, with some dynamic resistance, with some current density in the junction, with temperature, with some feedback from the collector voltage.

Because all of those complications means VBE varies by as much as 100mV in either direction, a good transistor design will have bias arrangements that allow for that variation in VBE without too large a variation in the collector current.

Comment: Isn't Vbe, just barrier potential?

Comment: Barrier potential is a simplified model of a semiconductor junction, useful for some things, but not an exact description of the way a transistor behaves. Useful tip, any time you find yourself using the word 'just', as in 'just barrier potential', it almost certainly means that you underestimate the complexity of the subject. It's taken a couple of decades, but I am making progress on eliminating the words just, simply, and only from my vocabulary.

Comment: @LoopBack “just” is a four letter word. Deeply frowned upon  in polite circles.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question - rather often, I have seen that there is some confusion regarding the role of the base-emitter voltage.

Let`s start with the **general statement**: The BJT is a voltage-controlled device - that means: The collector current is an exponential function of the base-emitter voltage Vbe. This is formulated in the famous Shockley equation **Ic=Io[exp(Vbe/Vt)-1]**. Because the base current Ib is (nearly) a fixed part of the collector current (1% or less), the relation Ib=f(Vbe) is also an exponential characteristic as shown in the above graph.

For using the BJT as an amplifier, we must bias the base-emitter diode with a DC voltage Vbe which is approximately in the range of 0.7 volts. This defines the so called "operational" point within the "quasi-linear" part of the exp. characteristic. However, due to several uncertainties (tolerances, temperature effects) we do not know the exact value of Vbe for a certain (wanted) collector current. Therefore, we use an emitter resistor RE which provides a certain amount of negative DC feedback - with the following result:

The actual DC collector current Ic will be less dependent on actual transistor parameters. Therefore, in most cases it is sufficient - **for calculation purposes only (!!)** - to use a fixed value Vbe=0.7 volts. This value is used to compute the resistors for the biasing network.

On the other hand, of course the base-emitter voltage will vary around this bias point as a result of a signal voltage to be amplified. This variation d(Vbe) is transferred to the output (Ic variation) with the transconductance gm of the BJT.

This transconductance gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe) depends directly on the selected DC current Ic. This transconductance is simply the slope of the curve Ic=f(Vbe) and can be found to be gm=Ic/Vt (Vt=temperature voltage, app 26mV)

In the attached graph it is demonstrated how an emitter resistor RE can remarkably reduce the influence of circuit uncertainties (tolerances, temp. effects) on the resulting DC current Ic. Therefore, it is not too important if we set VBE=0.7 V or VBE=0.65 V during the calculation process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lets plot the input base-emitter voltage and current, on different axis.

In fact, lets use linear-voltage on horizontal axis, and use log-current on vertical axis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8hAUK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage changes 58 milliVolts, for each 10:1 change in current. Increase or decrease, the sign changes, but the magnitude is 58 milliVolts.
From 1 milliAmp to 10 nanoAmps, which is 5 orders of magnitude, we expect 5 * 0.058, or about 5 * 0.06 = 0.300 volts change in the diode voltage.

Or 18 milliVolts for 2:1 change in current (BandGap voltage reference designs will have 18 milliVolts, or multiples thereof, deep inside the design math).

Beware of strong temperature effects. And semiconductor processing effects. The 58mV is
for ideal transistors and diodes.